# How to decompress SVGZ with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael, svgz

I'm trying to set up this world map using SVGZ instead of SVG so I can give my users a richer, more detailed map.

So far I've tried decompressing it using [js-deflate](https://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate/), but to no avail.

Comment: SVGZ uses gzip for compressing. Browser doesn't decompress SVG without assistance?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question over and over.  Also, if you cannot ask a question without redirecting people to your website, then that question isn't acceptable here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I write in comment SVGZ uses `gzip`. Top browsers can decompress `gzip` files without assistance. Your page http://home.no/dwaynie/map load .svgz file with `Content-Type:text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1`. But for `SVG`|`SVGZ` it's not valid MIME type.

```
svg     Content-Type: image/svg+xml

svgz    Content-Type: image/svg+xml
        Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Above headers must be configured in web server (IIS, Apache).

Answer (score 4):

If you want the SVG file *inside* of the SVGZ, you gunzip it (it's a renamed archive):

```
cp file.svgz file2.svg.gz
gunzip file2.svg.gz
```

If you want to *use* a SVGZ image, then you might run into trouble. I think some browsers support it (virtually all support Gzip compression), but I doubt many do (if any at all).

Answer (score 0):

Just below the map on the page you refer to there's a link to Wikipedia that explains what it is: an SVG file compressed with gzip.

For completeness sake: gzip and (pk)zip are not the same format, but Windows tools like WinRAR and [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) understand gzip as well as zip.  Every Linux distro probably has gzip/gunzip installed by default.